# Extract the first and last non-zero row and column from a binary matrix in R

Tags: r

The idea is to create a box(draw the lines) around an image which is represented as a binary matrix. For that I need to extract the first and last non-zero row and column on each of the four sides.
For exemplification, here is a snippet that creates the figure bellow:

```
R = 50; b = 10
x = 1:(3*R); y = x; x.cent = R; y.cent = R; r = R-b
A = outer(x, y, function(x,y) sqrt(((x-x.cent)^2)+((y-y.cent)^2)))
circle <- ifelse(A<r, 1, 0)
```

[image]

The circle is for exemplification purpose. In reality it can be any shape.
True, it can be done by slicing each side and look for each row/column for non-zero values but I'm looking for an elegant way to do it to be computationally fast.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example ?

Comment: A box around the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rowSums()` and `colSums()` to identify the indices of non-zero row/column sums and then use `range()` to exract the first and last values.

```
range(which(rowSums(circle) != 0))
# [1] 11 89

range(which(colSums(circle) != 0))
# [1] 11 89
```